# Why eval works where macro doesn't when building WHERE conditions in Korma

Tags: sql, clojure, korma

I'm trying to dynamically add WHERE conditions to Korma SQL query

```
(-> the-query
    (where {:archived false})
    (add-where-conditions params)
    (limit 200)
    (select))
```

I'm trying to dynamically build call to korma's *where* function. The call would look something like `(where query (or (between :freq [100 200]) (between :freq [300 400]) ... ))`. The helper function *make-conds* makes a *list* of the arguments for *where* function like: `(or (between :freq [100 200]) ...`

I attempted the following approaches to build the dynamic where call. Only the **first one**, the one with `eval` works. Why? Is there a better way to do this?

```
(defn add-where-conditions [query params]
  (eval (list 'where query (make-conds params))))

(defmacro add-where-conditions-2 [query params]
  (list 'where query (make-conds params))) ; broken

(defmacro add-where-conditions-3 [query params]
  `(where ~query ~(make-conds params))) ; broken
```

Disclaimer: I'm a newbie to Clojure and Korma

Comment: could you include the exact error message? if it by chance "can't take value of a macro"?

Comment: Please also post the definition for `make-conds` as well, I understand that this is function you defined yourself, is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the macros don't work is that in both cases the value for the `params` argument is the symbol `params`. This is why in `add-where-conditions-2` and `add-where-conditions-3` when the macros make the call `(make-conds params)`, the value that function receives is not the list you are thinking of but the symbol `params`, showing an error in the lines of:

```
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)
```

The first case works because the function receives the list (not the symbol) as the value for the `params` argument, so `eval` receives the list `(where {:your-query nil} (or (between :freq [100 200]) ,,,))`, which is what the `where` macro expects and knows how to handle.

The [`where`](http://korma.github.io/Korma/korma.core.html#var-where) macro parses the expression in search of some predicates which it uses to build expressions. [`where*`](http://korma.github.io/Korma/korma.core.html#var-where%2a), the function alternative, doesn't have that kind of functionality, so I can't think of an alternative to `eval` for eating the cake and having it too.